# Как мониторить позиции сайта в поисковый выдаче?

Tags: seo, php

Задача: пользователь вводит домен и ключевые слова, после чего ему выдается таблица позиций в поисковой выдаче гугла и яндекса по данным ключевым словам.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это возможно реализовать. Код не нужен, просто схематично объясните.

Готовые сервисы тоже не интересуют:)

Comment: Может через API как-нибудь? (если есть такое)

Comment: [Поиск работает](http://php.su/articles/?cat=examples&page=048)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно реализовать с помощью Google Search API и Yandex XML.
Примерная схема скрипта:

1. Отправляем поисковику запрос с выбранными ключевыми словами;
2. Парсим ответ поисковика, считая каждый сайт в выдаче;
3. Найдя нужный сайт, выводим об этом сообщение и высчитанную позицию сайта.

Есть нюанс: максимальное количество найденных Google'ом сайтов в выдаче - 64, а Yandex'ом, кажется, 500.

Comment: Да, спасибо, про yandex xml я уже прочитала, а вот search api для гугл возьму на заметку:)